# How to copy from Azure to the storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

How can I copy all data from Azure into a local storage emulator? I want to include tables, blobs and queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automated way to do this, it will simply be using the API or your 3rd party tool of choice (e.g. ClumsyLeaf) to copy tables and blobs.  You can drag/drop for blobs with a tool like that and export/import as well for tables (CloudXplorer and TableXplorer respectively).

Things to keep in mind are that the limitations of the storage emulator is different than cloud and you might end up with issues (max blob size and handing of date times perhaps).  I guess you can always try and if it is not a ton of data you can compensate manually.

Have not heard a lot of reasons why you would want to do that however... mind sharing the use case?